# Managing large vectors with MPI I/O in C

Tags: c++, c, io, mpi, hpc

I am trying to compute the distance function matrix for a set of spatial coordinates (x and y ) with index array "a". The following is a simplified script wherein I scatter only the index array into local array local_a for each process. Instead of evaluating the entire distance matrix , I only compute the upper triangular matrix without the trivial diagonal entries which are essentially zero. I am trying to use MPI I/O to compute the Euclidean distance "d" and store it in an array and then write that array to an output file. I define the offset as a function of local_a[i] which defines both the local dimension as (SIZE-local_a), since the # of elements decrease as one moves down in row for an upper triangular matrix.  The code below works well for up to 8000 elements but fails with "  mca_fbtl_posix_pwritev: error in writev:Invalid argument " when I use 80,000 as vector size. I am not sure what is causing this error and any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int procid, numprocs, ierr, *a, SIZE, num_rows;
    SIZE = 80000;
    MPI_File fh;

    double *x, *y, tstart, tend;

    a = (int*) malloc(SIZE*sizeof(int));
    x =(double*) malloc(SIZE*sizeof(double));
    y =(double*) malloc(SIZE*sizeof(double));

    ierr = MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    ierr = MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &procid);
    ierr = MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numprocs);

    MPI_Status status;
    MPI_Offset offset;

    num_rows = SIZE/numprocs;

    for ( int i = 0; i < SIZE; i ++)
    {   
            a[i] = i+1;
            x[i] = i+1;
            y[i] = i+2;
    }

    // Define local array for each process

    int *local_a;

    local_a = (int*) malloc(num_rows*sizeof(int));

    // Scatter only the index array (a) to each process in a cyclical manner

        for (int i = 0; i < num_rows; i ++)
        {
            ierr = MPI_Scatter(&a[i*numprocs], 1, MPI_INT, &local_a[i], 1, MPI_INT,  0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            
        }     


    MPI_File_open(MPI_COMM_WORLD, "data.bin", MPI_MODE_CREATE|MPI_MODE_WRONLY, MPI_INFO_NULL, &fh);

    for ( int i  = 0; i < num_rows ; i++)
    {
       int p1 = local_a[i];
       int local_dim  = (SIZE-local_a[i]);

        double *Dist;
        Dist = (double*) malloc(local_dim*sizeof(double));

       if ( local_a[i]==1)
       {
           offset = 2*0*sizeof(int);
       }

       else
       {
         int sum  =0;

         for ( int i = (SIZE-1); i >local_dim; i--)
         {
             sum +=i;
         }

         offset = 2*sum*sizeof(int);

        if ( local_dim == 0)
         {
             local_dim = 1;
         }
       }
    
      for ( int j = local_a[i]; j < SIZE; j++)
      {
          double d;
         
           d = pow((pow(x[p1-1]-x[j],2) + pow(y[p1 -1]-y[j],2)),0.5);
           Dist[j-local_a[i]] = d;
      } 

        ierr = MPI_File_write_at(fh,offset,Dist,local_dim,MPI_DOUBLE,&status);
                   
        ierr = MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);          

        free(Dist);

    }

     MPI_File_close(&fh);

    ierr = MPI_Finalize();

    free(a);
    free(x);
    free(y);
    free(local_a);


    return ierr;
    
}
```

Comment: checking the return values of `malloc` and all the `MPI_` calls for errors might be a good place to start.

Comment: Since you tagged as C++, prefer to use `std::vector`, as it manages memory for you.

Comment: Since you tagged as C++, prefer to use `operator new` and `operator delete`.  The `operator new` will call the class or struct constructor; `malloc` doesn't do that.

Comment: how many MPI tasks are you running? on how many nodes? which version of Open MPI ?